# How can I create multiple types & params for custom events?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cc

I have a custom event class and want to insert multiple parameters (like the native events: MOUSE_UP, CLICK, ROLL_OVER). Here's my code so far:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MenuGeneratorEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const PASS_PARAMS:String = "passParams";

        public var param1:String = new String();

        public function MenuGeneratorEvent(type:String, str:*, bubbles:Boolean = false,
                                                cancelable:Boolean = false):void
        {
            this.param1 = str;

            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

        override public function clone():Event
        {
            return new MenuGeneratorEvent(type, param1, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Flash Professional CC 2015. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It is totally possible to do it this way. But your question doesn't seem to point to your actual problem. At least this is what I read from the comments below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them as construcor arguments and make it visible outside just like you did with `param1`.
If you have to many parameters to pass as constructor arguments you can always wrap them inside another object. An if you want have access to them directly from event object just create accessors to them:

```
public class MenuGeneratorEvent extends Event
{
    public static const PASS_PARAMS:String = "passParams";

    private var params:Object;

    public function MenuGeneratorEvent(type:String, params:Object, bubbles:Boolean = false,
                                            cancelable:Boolean = false):void
    {
        this.params = params;

        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new MenuGeneratorEvent(type, params, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

    public function get param1():String{return params.param1;}
    public function get param2():Number{return params.param2;}
    public function get param3():Object{return params.param3;}
}
```

Comment: hello, I tried your code however couldn't make it work correctly. please have a look at this code: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/616385/    what am I doing wrong? I'm not getting any output.

Comment: No, no, no... The params is just argument for event object constructor. You pass it when you create an event so later when you listen this events you can access this parameters like `event.param1`.

Comment: If you want multiple event TYPES then you create multiple static consts like you did with PASS_PARAMS. Then you can get this type from your event class. And those consts are just to be consistent. You can even try this to write something like `dispatchEvent(new MenuGeneratorEvent("blabla", "test"));` and sill listen this event - `addEventListener("blabla", onProcessedEvent);`

Comment: thanks for helping. I'm still having trouble with this. this is what I tried: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/616457/    it doesn't output anything. I'm sure there's something little I miss, however I can't figure it out.

Comment: dispatch event after you start listening it?

Comment: o.k. it's working fine after I swap the two lines, though I can't understand why. thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, when you dispatch event it ist dispatched to all registered listeners. When you add listener after the event is dispatched, your callback function is never called. It's like taking a photo and then after that take of the lens cover ;)