# EventDispatch error in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am not sure if something is wrong with my code or if I have to handle the error differently. I have an instance of Gear and the other one is bLine. I am trying to make both move as soon as the gear falls on the line. So what I have inside of the instance coded is:

```
var ev2:Event = new Event("transfer");

dispatchEvent(ev2);


stop();
```

In the bLine I have:
  `

```
import flash.events.Event;

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Move);

function Move(e:Event):void {
    this.x=this.x+3;

};
```

Then, in the main timeline:

```
 import flash.events.Event;
gear.addEventListener("transfer",transferGear);

function transferGear(e:MouseEvent) {
bLine.gotoAndPlay(2);

 };
```

This is the output I'm getting:
"TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@16bbd6bb7821 to flash.events.MouseEvent.
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()

at Rube2_fla::mc_gear_4/frame24()"

So what am I doing wrong and how I could fix it?

Comment: Try `(e:Event)` or even `(e:Event = null)` instead of _(e:MouseEvent)_. Your _gear.addEventListener_ has no mouse events defined so later the function `transferGear` cannot be told to expect input of type `MouseEvent`

Comment: You are awesome, thank you so much. I didn't even notice that!!

Comment: PS: The point of using `(e:Event = null)` it allows you to **also** use same function even at those times when not involving some event. For that just do a `transferGear();` anytime to make `bLine` go to frame 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change function parameter:

```
function transferGear(e:Event) {...}
```

Or event class you are dispatching.

```
new MouseEvent("transfer");
```

But in this case you are crating more additional field that you don't need (like local X)

Most iteally you would extend Event class with your own and use define some custom static types to work like this:

```
gear.addEventListener(MyOwesomeEvent.TRANSFER,transferGear);
```

You may probably want to also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126410/how-can-i-create-multiple-types-params-for-custom-events/32127562#32127562)

**Suggestions**

If you want to do more advance stuff than simply play some animation or click a button then I would suggest to install [some IDE](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/getting_started.html) and separate your code from your `.fla` file.

Flash develop for example generate event listener code automatically when you hit `ctrt + shift + 1` so it is hard to make a mistake. It something looks like this (not edited, system out of RAM... :/).

[image]

Also by convention we start function names from lower case letter so you can distinguish it from a class.